# gedit unresponsive how to save my file?

Tags: linux, redhat, gedit

I have created a document and have not saved it yet. The gedit has become unresponsive. Is there anyway I can save or get the content of my file before killing the process?

Answer (score 1):

gedit will create a backup file called `filename~` in the same folder as the edited file. It will contain the contents before last save. If you have saved the file during edit it may contain at least a part of the contents

Comment: I did not have it saved! any solution?

Comment: unfortunately not. except from making a screenshot. sorry

Comment: when the contents aren't saved, they only exist in the memory space of the gedit process. It is by design that no other processes can access this memory regions. Only the gedit process which is hanging or the kernel could access this memory. You can try to obtain a core dump: http://serverfault.com/questions/173999/dump-a-linux-processs-memory-to-file

Comment: Another idea would be to stop gedit from hanging. are you able to obtain the pid of gedit?

Comment: when I ps it I get some pid but im not sure if they are the right ones. so what do u suggest to stop it from hanging?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32247/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-comerun)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to start gedit as root and then save your file.

[Starting as root](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-can-i-log-in-as-root/).

Then you could do `$gedit filename`
and try to save it.